# Entity Framework 6 Code First - Relations with a different DataBase

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, relational-database

I need to develop a program that manages shops. I have 5 different shops now, and the number will increase in the future. I am planning to create one database (with SQL Server) for every shop, and one more database that contains shared information. Something like this:

[image]

Every database has the exactly same structure (with approximately 20 tables) and has multiple relationship with the Shared Database. I know how to arrange something like this in ADO.Net but I want to try with Entity Framework Code First. I am at a quite basic level in EF now, but I think this is a good chance to improve my knowledge in this topic. I have tried a possible solution creating multiple DbContext each one pointing to a different DataBase. Everything works perfectly, but I can’t figure out how to manage the relations with the Shared DataBase. I’ve read a lot on this topic, and it seems to me that working with different DBs is possible since version 6 of EF. This is the version that I am using. Is it possible to achieve this with the “standard” EF syntax? Have I to manage all the relationships with the shared DB “manually”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered my question, I'm going to explain what I've done. After many other research, I didn't find much about the right way to operate with multiple databases in EF. But I got what I needed and perhaps someone can find this kind of useful. First of all, we need to face the facts here: working with multiple database is bad for EF, even for EF 6. In my opinion, you can get the cleanest solution using ado.net for connection management. In this way you can get the ID of the joining records and use it in other queries. You can write a function, just passing the information you need and the reference of the database, that’s not so hard to implement. 
Anyway, after many other considerations, I think is better reconsidering the use of only one database.